# How to access and update an item continously from DynamoDB in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to update the percentage of process of a AWS Lambda function. I have also modify my python script to write in database the process percentage. 
I now would like to get it from my javascript code, and update it to display the process to the user. 
I'm using the code like this, but I think it's not a good thing to put it in a while loop...

```
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
  var paramsT = {
  Key: {
     "userId": {
       S: this.state.userId
      },
     "noteId": {
       S: this.state.noteId
      }
    },
    TableName: "notes"
 };

 ddb.getItem(paramsT, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     this.setState({ percentage: data['Item']['percentage']['N'] });            // successful response
 }.bind(this));
console.log("End of request");
```

Can someone explain me how to achieve this ?

Comment: It’s not exactly clear what your question really is. Can you please update the question to show what problem ypu are facing? The code in the question seems fine for reading the percentage item. And I assume by ‘update’ you mean update in the UI!?

Comment: Absolutely yes, I want to update the percentage every 1sec for example, in order to display an "accurate" value in the UI.

Comment: What starts the lambda (said differently, what is the relationship between this JS front-end and your lambda function)? Please try to update your question because as it is written it’s hard to understand what the system looks like. Also - are you just asking if the approach is good, or is the code you have not working?

Comment: You shouldn’t put that in a for-loop. Instead, you might set up an 1000 ms interval and stick the code that your have for reading from Dynamo and updating the percentage on the UI there, in the setInterval callback. You could also do the same with setTimeout but you’d have to explicitly be calling setTimeout each time